# XSD restrictions - whiteSpace "replace", but spaces not allowed

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

What happens when whitespace is put into a message that follows the following XML Schema?

```
<xs:whiteSpace value="replace"/>
<xs:pattern value="[\-\*0-9A-Z]{12}"/>
```

Would the whitespace be replaced with spaces, and then it fail validation? Or would something else happen?

Comment: I think that your pattern changes the behaviour of whitespace, furthermore if you use {12} , min and max lenght are redundant.

Comment: good point, thanks. edited. How does it change it, do you know?

Comment: @Xstian is right (although I'd simply say the pattern rejects spaces, making `xs:whiteSpace` irrelevant).  Varying the `xs:pattern` regular expression can [illustrate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29967467/290085) that.

Comment: is there something that happens at a lower level if the schema is as described? Would the whitespace be replaced with spaces, and then the message rejected because of the pattern? Or would it not even bother checking? i.e., would the rejection be because of a tab character, or because of a space character, if <elementName>\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\element> was used?

Comment: The 12 tab chars would be converted to spaces, then the regex would fail to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `xs:pattern` regular expression does not allow spaces, and the `xs:whiteSpace` facet will not change that.

### Full XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:whiteSpace value="replace"/>
        <xs:pattern value="[\-\*0-9A-Z]{12}"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

### XML

This XML will be ***valid***:

```
<root>123456789012</root>
```

This XML will be ***invalid*** because of the space:

```
<root>1234567890 2</root>
```

---

If the XSD were changed to allow spaces,

```
        <xs:pattern value="[ \-\*0-9A-Z]{12}"/>
```

and the XML had, say, a tab in it:

```
<root>1234567890    2</root>
```

then the `xs:whiteSpace` value would replace it with a space, and *now* the XSD would find the XML to be ***valid***.

Comment: so, if a tab character was put in the value, would it convert it to a space before rejecting it?

Comment: As I said in above comment, I agreed with @kjhughes

Comment: @simonalexander2005, yes, you understand correctly.  Answer updated.